# Error with pool() during multivariage multiple missing impuation with mice package

Tags: missing-data, survey, mice

Someone who is an expert!
I am a new learner about missing data imputation using R and mice package.
Thank you in advance for your response.

I encountered an error with pool(), I cannot find any relevant explanation on my search.

```
data <-iris

# Generate 10% missing values ar random

library (missForest)
iris.mis <-prodNA (iris, noNA = 0.1)

# removing categorical data
iris.mis <- subset (iris.mis, select = -c(Species))

#mice package
library (mice)

## imputing missing data with mice libray
imputed_Data <- mice(iris.mis, m=5, maxit = 50, method = 'pmm', seed = 500)

### build predictive model
fit <- with(data = iris.mis, expr = lm(Sepal.Width ~ Sepal.Length + Petal.Width)) 

### combine results of all 5 models
pool(fit)
```

The error from the last line, pool(fit):

```
Error: No tidy method for objects of class qr
In addition: Warning messages:
1: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
See help("Deprecated")
. (same error messages are repeated)
6: 'tidy.numeric' is deprecated.
See help("Deprecated")
```

I cannot get any information for this error in help("Deprecated").
How can I solve this problem?
And How can I get one combined data of five imputed dataset using mice package?
I am using R 4.0.0 and mice package 3.9.0, windows 10.

Comment: You might get more help on a site more oriented to programming. You might try leaving the tidyverse first and using base R functions and see if that helps.

Comment: I have the exact same problem.